# Laravel + Passport - why does "auth:api" send me to login form?

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth, laravel-passport

Using Laravel (5.4) + Passport (4.0) I am trying to implement an oAuth authorization for my api. Getting the token is no problem, but as soon I access the wanted ressource at http://somedomain.tld/api/user I get somehow tossed to the web login form. My request holds all necessary headers as:

```
[{"key":"Authorization","value":"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImYxODk3ZmVhODIyOGQ0ZGY5MzU0ODI3NThiZTdlMmU0NTVjN2NkMzExMjc5OTdhMzU3NTQ3ZDQ5NzhhYTVmNjdjMTc5NmVlNTVjZGE4OTIyIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiZjE4OTdmZWE4MjI4ZDRkZjkzNTQ4Mjc1OGJlN2UyZTQ1NWM3Y2QzMTEyNzk5N2EzNTc1NDdkNDk3OGFhNWY2N2MxNzk2ZWU1NWNkYTg5MjIiLCJpYXQiOjE1MDQxMTAzNzMsIm5iZiI6MTUwNDExMDM3MywiZXhwIjoxNTA1NDA2MzczLCJzdWIiOiIiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.WadULiSlQBJtG2Ixag8kGyI82UdXxHBGRWVJEb6ro4HGKPMpDl6-SRkp0EPV8ZJN2fZpv43g-bkJc-xVqPPHgx42QmDacOWeBcEb4kT5lYR6H540F_VmVUkB7ZRxNeEhX3cXysNmwRxrdbEvks3ml5S6pT1SSh2iDvYVk3xeAFhXv6GNBuy_3IOxaRwa9svXH7fR8n1YoJub8dnJM9xoGgXaxGFUoddjYMJNDjE7WYFHKePYES4ovp74OnPngJp62864kQ-8MEZmMaPPYmRX9SmSei-9VmWrdo5c9MyDBIDNgZpFF34bfA843LzSqgz1qDf26msjJX28tbP70fmNa1k5vt2OSYWVIB-G3eH280357VZbcbFmL34SqoAUOaWNjrLGPajBeVtqQO1sLW0y_662-b5ei3X4aZgDv09cfmll5IvkH1qsPYoB3ieBVkI8Fpet6T0p2-0iQjW9tClhGATlBMpEI67FIVBOFxw37YBmJSuj76XCd4MV0KVizWtLKpQZrYw64Kr9ncRMVf2fEsdUMZ6XahPBioTsC_CEkf9EgSBjKM-6l6P5C0yM51IbbUpjsjTZcfpzavuSDyOkrg2B_oSU9u_a2oX_K2NQyERxvsmJgkmV5FWol84GaNgPQZHOSekwdI52EobMAMFBapgjWVqjvhLagazWFsK9crI","description":""},{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","description":""}]

[{"key":"Accept-Encoding","value":"application/json","description":""}]

[{"key":"Accept-Encoding","value":"application/json","description":""}]
```

my **routes/api.php** reads

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

but somehow I keep getting sent to the web login form.
Anyone who can explain me? I already posted a [more detailed question with all sourcecode here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/oauth-with-passport-keeps-sending-me-to-login-form).

Comment: How you get this token ? And and how you do setting to header. I mean how you ensure that token is valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these headers while requesting through AJAX, jQuery handles this automatically for you but for other frameworks it needs to be done manually.

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: This is it. After adding that header I am no longer getting tossed to the login form, but I am getting an 401 unauthenticated now.

Comment: Try logging in again and using the new tokens and also make sure that middleware is assigned properly, by default it should be just auth:api.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel checks if you sent an ajax request or not. You can send this header information to your api to get a json response and no redirect:

`Accept : application/json`

Another way is to write a middleware, where you set the header before it will be passed to the routes:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->server->set('HTTP_ACCEPT', 'application/json');
    $request->headers = new HeaderBag($request->server->getHeaders());
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Of course I meant the header "Accept:application/json" instead of putting the header "Accept-Encoding:application/json" twice as I did in my question. Been just a copy/paste error.